# Qt program not executable (Exec format error) despite binary and system architecture both x86_64

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get a hello world example working with the latest version of Qt on Ubuntu 20.04. I am compiling via the automatically generated `Makefile` produced by `qmake`. Once compiled, the binary does not have sufficient permissions. After granting permissions I get an `Exec format error`. Running `file` on the output executable returns `ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped`. Running `uname -mpi` on my machine outputs `x86_64 x86_64 x86_64`. It seems to me like the architecture and binary are compatible but for some reason I get the `Exec format error`. Am I misunderstanding something or do I need to configure the compilation step in the `Makefile` to be compatible with my hardware?

Comment: I wonder if it is one of the shared libraries that your executable is linking to that is the culprit?  You might want to run `ldd` with your executable file as the argument, and see what shared libraries it is linking to, and then see what architecture they are compiled for.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner The result of ```ldd hello.o``` is ```not a dynamic executable```. Not sure if that implies some other problem.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to execute the wrong file.  `hello.o` is not an executable file, it's an object file.  The executable is usually named e.g. `hello`, with no extension.